# Show UIViewController on DetailDisclosureButton pressed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard, xcode-storyboard

I am attempting to get a UIViewController (GUI built using storyboard), to show when a `DetailDisclosureButton` is touched/pressed. I made a very simple GUI, with just a single button on the screen. I gave it the Custom Class `NFLGameDetailsController`, and did nothing else on the storyboard.
[image]

I then created a class named `NFLGameDetailsController` that inherited from the class `UIViewController`.

This is the code generated by Xcode when inheriting from the `UIViewController` class:

```
#import "NFLGameDetailsController.h"

@interface NFLGameDetailsController ()

@end

@implementation NFLGameDetailsController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Finally, on my main controller I added `#import "NFLGameDetailsController.h"` to my header file, and implemented the method to show my UIViewController like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NFLGameDetailsController *controller = [[NFLGameDetailsController alloc] init];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

This method is getting called and all seems fine, but when I do press an accessory detail disclosure button, I get a black screen:

[image]

Why is it that it is not showing the GUI I created using the storyboard? Thanks.

Comment: Your initializers suggest that you've coded your UI sans StoryBoards (obviously not the case).  Either override -init and setup programmatically, or use `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`

Comment: Sorry, but I have been messing around with the `performSegueWithIdenitifier:sender:`, and I am just confused... When using it, should I call it like this:`NFLGameDetailsController *controller = [[NFLGameDetailsController alloc] init];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gameDetailsSegue" sender:controller];`

Comment: You shouldn't even have to alloc and init anything (the storyboard does that for you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it`s because you are instantiating just a class , not a view

if you want to load another view from code you can do this way

first , assign Storyboard ID to your viewcontroller in Storyboard editor ( for example NFLGameDetailsController )

then

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NFLGameDetailsController *controller = (NFLGameDetailsController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NFLGameDetailsController"];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

but you could use storyboard editor to configure your tableview and its` cell to load another view without code